# Count two columns if both columns are filled with text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have two columns with different text in it, for example:

```
Col a:    Col b:
a         dw
b         
c         cc   
d
e         dw
```

How do I need to set up my `COUNTIF()` formula to count both columns only when both columns are filled with text?

I hope someone can help me with this!

Comment: Use `=COUNTIFS()` instead to use multiple ranges and thus multiple criteria, e.g.: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>",B:B,"<>")`

Comment: Wauw it worked! Thanks. But for some reason my Excel wanted to use '';'' instead of '',''